# How to develop project using T4 template that can create database,database tables etc like entity framework works

Tags: t4

I want to use T4 template for generation of code,that can take input from windows form and create my projects depend on input of form.I want to create database,database tables like entity framework create the database module for us.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use T4 templates in runtime mode:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx

Collect your data from form and pass them to T4 template (in constructor for example).

Constructor create in partial class for template.